# Google Maps - Show many markers in a map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have tried for some time now to display multiple markers in a map and I keep running into errors.
I have managed to come up with this code, but i get a crash.

Here is my mapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.moses.ngongapp;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;



    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        private ArrayList<LatLng> listLatLng;
        private RelativeLayout rlMapLayout;
        HashMap<Marker, LatLngBean> hashMapMarker = new HashMap<Marker, LatLngBean>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            rlMapLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMapLayout);

            setUpMapIfNeeded();
            setData();

        }

        private void setData() {
            ArrayList<LatLngBean> arrayList = new ArrayList<LatLngBean>();
            LatLngBean bean = new LatLngBean();
            bean.setTitle("Ahmedabad");
            bean.setSnippet("Hello,Ahmedabad");
            bean.setLatitude("23.0300");
            bean.setLongitude("72.5800");
            arrayList.add(bean);

            LatLngBean bean1 = new LatLngBean();
            bean1.setTitle("Surat");
            bean1.setSnippet("Hello,Surat");
            bean1.setLatitude("21.1700");
            bean1.setLongitude("72.8300");
            arrayList.add(bean1);

            LatLngBean bean2 = new LatLngBean();
            bean2.setTitle("Vadodara");
            bean2.setSnippet("Hello,Vadodara");
            bean2.setLatitude("22.3000");
            bean2.setLongitude("73.2000");
            arrayList.add(bean2);

            LoadingGoogleMap(arrayList);
        }

        /**
         * @author Hasmukh Bhadani
         * Set googleMap if require
         */
        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

            // Google Play Services are not available
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                int requestCode = 10;
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
                dialog.show();

            } else if (googleMap == null) {
                ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
                if (googleMap != null) {
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * @author Hasmukh Bhadani
         * Loading Data to the GoogleMap
         */
// -------------------------Google Map
        void LoadingGoogleMap(ArrayList<LatLngBean> arrayList) {
            if (googleMap != null) {
                googleMap.clear();
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
                    try {
                        listLatLng = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                            LatLngBean bean = arrayList.get(i);
                            if (bean.getLatitude().length() > 0 && bean.getLongitude().length() > 0) {
                                double lat = Double.parseDouble(bean.getLatitude());
                                double lon = Double.parseDouble(bean.getLongitude());

                                Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                                        .title(bean.getTitle())
                                        .snippet(bean.getSnippet())
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

                                //Add Marker to Hashmap
                                hashMapMarker.put(marker, bean);

                                //Set Zoom Level of Map pin
                                LatLng object = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                                listLatLng.add(object);
                            }
                        }
                        SetZoomlevel(listLatLng);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker position) {
                            LatLngBean bean = hashMapMarker.get(position);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bean.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        /**
         * @author Hasmukh Bhadani
         * Set Zoom level all pin withing screen on GoogleMap
         */
        public void SetZoomlevel(ArrayList<LatLng> listLatLng) {
            if (listLatLng != null && listLatLng.size() == 1) {
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(listLatLng.get(0), 10));
            } else if (listLatLng != null && listLatLng.size() > 1) {
                final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
                for (int i = 0; i < listLatLng.size(); i++) {
                    builder.include(listLatLng.get(i));
                }

                final ViewTreeObserver treeObserver = rlMapLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
                treeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        if (googleMap != null) {
                            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), findViewById(R.id.map)
                                    .getWidth(), findViewById(R.id.map).getHeight(), 80));
                            rlMapLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
```

my logcat is here

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.moses.ngongapp, PID: 28132
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moses.ngongapp/com.example.moses.ngongapp.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.moses.ngongapp.MapsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.moses.ngongapp.MapsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
    at com.example.moses.ngongapp.MapsActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsActivity.java:90)
    at com.example.moses.ngongapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:44)
```

Comment: Where is your onMapReady() method ?

Comment: @RishabhMahatha  it now loads but my markers are not shown, it gives the "sorry , unable to create maps"..why arent my markers visible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    this.googleMap = map;

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    setData()
}
```

Do map related stuff in `onMapReady()`.

Comment: The Activity has to implement `OnMapReadyCallback` for this to work

Comment: @cricket_007 it now loads but my markers are not shown, it gives the "sorry , unable to create maps"..why arent my markers visible??

Answer (score 1):

Error here

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
```

Error clearly says "`MapsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback`".

So, just implement that interface

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

And implement the corresponding `onMapReady` method from that interface.

Then, you don't need to cast. Just `getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this)`

Also don't do any `GoogleMap` related functions until *within or after* that method.

Regarding your comments, you have to trace your code as to exactly why `if (googleMap != null) {` is not being entered. Because the map is null - obviously. But why? Because `getMapAsync` will "wait"  until the map is ready, at which point `getMapAsync` is called at some undetermined point  in the future (hence Async, it runs in the background).

In other words, do not call the setUpMapIfNeeded or setData method in onCreate, but instead only when the map becomes available (from the parameter to the onMapReady method)

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    this.googleMap = map;

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    setData(); // this calls LoadingGoogleMap() 
}
```

If the markers still aren't visible, then continue to debug your code. This answer only is intended to address the error mentioned in the question.

---

<sup>By the way, [your previous question was already implementing the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181172/google-maps-activities-in-android)</sup>

Comment: it now loads but my markers are not shown, it gives the "sorry , unable to create maps"..why arent my markers visible??

Comment: Obviously. `else { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }`... In other words you didn't follow my note - don't do **any** GoogleMap related functions until within or after that getMapAsync method, otherwise **it is null**, and therefore you hit all those else statements

Comment: sorry but can you please clarify, there is a lot of code after that, where should i put them???? i am confused please

Comment: "until within or after that" what does this mean

Comment: Your map variable is null. Look at the other answer, for example. You call the other methods that need the map from **within** onMapReady. Therefore executing them **after** you have an available map (though that answer is missing assigning the map field). You should only call (or some code that eventually leads to) `LoadingGoogleMap` from onMapReady. And if you read your previous question I linked to, you'll send how to assign the field and add markers to the map from within onMapReady

Comment: And why did you accept the other answer if it didn't work for you?

Comment: @ cricket_007 i accepted it because it solved my crash problem, and as for the moment i still cant understand your instruction, i  have two sets of code here setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setData();,,, please just show me/write the code how it should be,,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130930/discussion-between-sir-george-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Suggestion: start back at the basics - the question I linked to that you previously asked was a direct copy from the official documentation. It adds a single marker to Nairobi perfectly fine, yes? (I think you changed that from Sydney, Australia). So, what understanding are you missing to get code after that marker to add a second one?

Answer (score 1):

You can imolement new method like **onMapReady**  and rest of the work regarding inti that method.

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).
    getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback()

            @Override
          public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
          this.googleMap = map;
          setUpMapIfNeeded();
          setData()
      });
```

Comment: can you help me make the markers visible, the code runs but my markers arent visible??